# Regex Match Punctuation Space but Retain Punctuation

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a large paragraph string which I'm trying to split into sentences using JavaScript's `.split()` method. I need a regex that will match a period or a question-mark `[?.]` followed by a space. However, I need to retain the period/question-mark in the resulting array. How can I do this without positive lookbehinds in JS?

Edit: Example input:
`"This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2? This is sentence 3."`
Example output:
`["This is sentence 1.", "This is sentence 2?", "This is sentence 3."]`

Comment: do you wanna split or match?if you want to match it can be done **[easily](https://regex101.com/r/gJ6vV4/1)**

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: Edited to clarify with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work

```
([^?.]+[?.])(?:\s|$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gJ6vV4/3)**

*JS Demo*

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/0TKE4g)**

```js
var str = 'This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2? This is sentence 3.';
var regex = /([^?.]+[?.])(?:\s|$)/gm;
var m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.writeln(m[1] + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: It seems like it works from that website. However, when I put it into my JS file, I get a random empty array value after every sentence, and the spaces are stuck in the result before every sentence in the array.

Comment: @whtat spaces will be handled now..try with `print` instead of `document.writeln`..where are you using it?

Comment: I still get the empty array values for some reason. I'm just using it on a page of my site to split a paragraph of text from a string. Then I'm printing each line out using a for loop.

Comment: @jswny you don't have to split if you are using this regex..it matches all the value  you want..if you will split on this regex it will obviously give empty array

Comment: Right, I've fixed it to match now and this works, thank you very much!

Comment: Got it, forgot, sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

Forget about split(). You want [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

```
var text = "This is an example paragragh. Oh and it has a question? Ok it's followed by some other random stuff. Bye.";

var matches = text.match(/[\w\s'\";\(\)\,]+(\.|\?)(\s|$)/g);


alert(matches);
```

The generated matches array contains each sentence:

```
    Array[4]
        0:"This is an example paragragh. "
        1:"Oh and it has a question? "
        2:"Ok it's followed by some other random stuff. "
        4:"Bye. "
```

Here is the fiddle with it for further testing: https://jsfiddle.net/uds4cww3/

*Edited to match end of line too.*

Comment: My paragraph has commas in it and those break this for some reason?

Comment: Edited to search for commas. How about ';'? You need specify the characters that are allowed between the brackets in the regex, escaping those that have regex significance.

Comment: Also ()ºª&%$#" and it goes on. But it is easy to add them. I added some of those, feel free to add more/remove some ;)

Comment: Seems like it should work now, but it's not allowing `'` in the array for some reason, even though it's in the regex.

Comment: seems like there's no need to escape '

Answer (score 0):

May be this one validates your array items

```
\b.*?[?\.](?=\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/R_vvE4kemAuaQvlM)

Comment: This only matches the last sentence of my string though. I need it to split the string into each sentence.

Comment: How about this one? Turned into non greedy and you may replace the `*` with a `+` depending on your case.

Comment: That just returns a bunch of spaces and then the very last sentence.

Comment: If the "last" sentence do not have a trailing white space after the period or question mark then your regex might be like this modified one.

Answer (score 0):

This is tacky, but it works:

```
var breakIntoSentences = function(s) {
  var l = [];
  s.replace(/[^.?]+.?/g, a => l.push(a));
  return l;
}

breakIntoSentences("how? who cares.")
["how?", " who cares."]
```

(Really how it works: the RE matches a string of not-punctuation, followed by *something*.  Since the match is greedy, that something is either punctuation or the end-of-string.)

This will only capture the first in a series of punctuation, so `breakIntoSentences("how???? who cares...")` also returns `["how?", " who cares."]`.  If you want to capture all the punctuation, use `/[^.?]+[.?]*/g` as the RE instead.

**Edit:**  Hahaha: Wavvves teaches me about `match()`, which is what the replace/push does.  You learn something knew every goddamn day.

In its minimal form, supporting three punctuation marks, and using ES6 syntax, we get:

```
const breakIntoSentences = s => s.match(/[^.?,]+[.?,]*/g)
```

Comment: @rock321987 -- I copied that from wavvves too.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.match` will do it:

```
(?:\s?)(.*?[.?])
```

I.e.:

```js
sentence = "This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2? This is sentence 3.";
result = sentence.match(/(?:\s?)(.*?[.?])/ig);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   document.write(result[i]+"<br>");
}
```